# CoreML to make app footprint smaller ( dlib face tracking )

Tags: ios, opencv, dlib, coreml

Is it possible to use CoreML in the upcoming iOS release to make apps using dlib's face tracker smaller in filesize?

Comment: It's hard to answer this without more specifics. How large is this dlib that you're referring to? What's the end application size? What part of its functionality would you like to replace? Can you train a model to perform this task?

Comment: http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2